# Syntax error when trying to use CONVERT within PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

When I try to execute the query below, I get error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'convert'

and I'm not sure where I made mistake. The data type for qty field is nchar so I used convert function for finding totals.

```
select column_date, [red] as red, [blue] as blue, [green] as green, [yellow] as yellow 
from
(select * from table1) as t1
pivot
(
sum(convert(int,qty)) 
For color in 
([red], [blue], [green], [yellow])
) as SumofQuantityforeachcolor
```

Here is the table

```
column_date | color | qty | supplier
1 June 2012 | red   | 2   | XY
1 June 2012 | red   | 1   | AB
1 June 2012 | blue  | 4   | CD
1 June 2012 | blue  | 1   | XY
2 June 2012 | yellow| 13  | CD
2 June 2012 | green | 45  | CD
2 June 2012 | blue  | 32  | AB
2 June 2012 | red   | 37  | XY
2 June 2012 | red   | 2   | XY
2 June 2012 | red   | 1   | AB
2 June 2012 | blue  | 4   | CD
3 June 2012 | red   | 1   | AB
3 June 2012 | blue  | 4   | CD
3 June 2012 | blue  | 1   | XY
3 June 2012 | yellow| 13  | CD
3 June 2012 | green | 45  | CD
3 June 2012 | blue  | 32  | AB
```

and so on...

Comment: No..in fact the datatype is nchar.....I used word 'text' instead of nchar just to mean it is just a string.sorry for confusing..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `select *` in your sub query. List all columns you need and do the type cast in the field list instead of in the `sum()` function.

The aggregate function in a pivot does not take an expression as an argument. You have to specify a column.

```
<pivot_clause> ::=
        ( aggregate_function ( value_column [ [ , ]...n ]) 
        FOR pivot_column 
        IN ( <column_list> ) 
    )
```

You are probably looking for something like this.

```
select column_date, [red] as red, [blue] as blue, [green] as green, [yellow] as yellow 
from (
     select column_date,
            color,
            cast(qty as int) as qty
     from table1
     ) as T
pivot
     (
     sum(qty) 
     for color in ([red], [blue], [green], [yellow])
     ) as SumofQuantityforeachcolor
```

[SE-Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/74708)

Comment: yeah I listed all columns which i want and used like this `sum(cast(qty as int))` but doesn't work either 
it gets the same message `Incorrect Syntax near '('`

Comment: You should use `cast(qty as int) as qty` in the field list.

Comment: Valid point `Don't use select * in your sub query` I didn't know about it. Now I corrected it and query worked fine. Thanks again for every one.

Comment: @Erikson. 
It puts "NULL" for null values. I tried like this while selecting field - `isnull(cast(qty) as integer),0)` but it doesn't work..is there any work around for this? Thank you

Comment: Add `isnull(Red, 0) as Red` etc... to the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with `cast(gty as int)` ?

Comment: `cast(qty as int)` gives error
**Incorrect Syntax near '('"**